# Can anyone decypher why this 'find unique values' process doesn't work as intended?

Tags: c

The goal is that for a variable that is an array of:

```
typedef struct {
 GLuint vertex;
 GLuint normal;
} indice_pairs_t;
```

, we want to find all the pairs that are unique and put them in an appropriate order of appearance with unique pair indices intact.

For example: if initial pairs are

```
2 3
6 7
6 7
4 5
```

(the 2nd and 3rd pairs are same)

then the final order will be

```
0 1 1 2
```

('2 3' was 0, first '6 7' was 1 but also the second '6 7'; '4 5' was 2 and so on)

The following code attempts to do that but final order appears to be always '0 1 2 3 4 5' and so on. If 'break;' is removed, it becomes a mess; too many increments.

```
// First is always unique and first in order:
unique[0] = pairs[0];
order[0] = 0;
num_unique = 1;

// Skip first, we just did it:
for (i = 1; i < num_pairs; i++) {

 // Check if what we have is already the same
 for (y = 0; y < num_unique; y++) {

  if (unique[y].vertex == pairs[i].vertex&&unique[y].normal == pairs[i].normal) {
   /* A new pair was found to be the same; put the old unique index in order;
    keep num of unique items same: */
   order[i] = y;
  } else {
   /* A new pair was unique; copy it in unique pairs and increment number
    of unique items; put in order the new number */
   unique[num_unique] = pairs[i];
   order[i] = num_unique;
   num_unique++; // it follows since it was already incremented to 1.
   break;
  }

 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pretty  inefficient algorithm. The complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>). You could do better, by using a sorted sequence.

What you have is obviously buggy, but the idea seems clear. For every new value (next `i`) it is checked, if that value is already among unique values stored so far. That's what the inner loop is for. If the match is found, `order[i] = y` and the next `i` should be checked, so you can `break`. If the match is not found for current `y` however, you need to check next `y`. Only after all `y` were checked, you know the value is unique, so the part in the else clause should be moved outside the inner loop. I think the fixed version should look like this:

```
unique[0] = pairs[0];
order[0] = 0;
num_unique = 1;

// Skip first, we just did it:
for (i = 1; i < num_pairs; i++) {

    // Check if what we have is already the same
    for (y = 0; y < num_unique; y++) {

        if (unique[y].vertex == pairs[i].vertex && unique[y].normal == pairs[i].normal) {
            /*  A new pair was found to be the same; put the old unique index in order;
                keep num of unique items same: */
            order[i] = y;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(y == num_unique){
    /* No match was found in the inner loop,
       so y reached num_unique. You could use a flag
       to indicate this, which might be more readable*/

        /*  A new pair was unique; copy it in unique pairs and increment number
            of unique items; put in order the new number */
        unique[num_unique] = pairs[i];
        order[i] = num_unique;
        num_unique++; // it follows since it was already incremented to 1 in the beginning.
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's O(n²). The algorithm would benefit a lot from using a simple hash-table.